# Passing value from collectionView to new VC - Property initializers run before "self" is available (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, json, swift, collectionview

Trying to pass a value selected in a collectionView into a new View Controller to determine which local json file to decode. Get the error "Cannot use instance member 'selectedCategory' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Initial VC:

```
extension MenuViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

...

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectImageViewController") as! SelectImageViewController
    selectedVC.selectedCategory = categories[indexPath.row].category
    navigationController?.pushViewController(selectedVC, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Second VC:

```
class SelectImageViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var selectedCategory: String = ""

var selectedArray = Bundle.main.decode([Images].self, from: "\(selectedCategory).json") 

 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
 ...
}
```

I tried the lazy var and init methods suggested in other posts with this error, but no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "but no luck."? How exactly did you try them? What are the errors that you got?

Comment: i get the same "initializers run before 'self' is available error with lazy var. I'm admittedly not too familiar with init - tried adding my properties individually inside of an init() { } and got 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UIViewController'.

Comment: What exactly did you make lazy? You should make `selectedArray` lazy, not `selectedCategory`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run code which refers to `self` outside of a method (unless it's declared as `lazy`)

It's simpler to decode the array before presenting the controller

```
extension MenuViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

...

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectImageViewController") as! SelectImageViewController
    let selectedCategory = categories[indexPath.row].category
    selectedVC.selectedArray = Bundle.main.decode([Images].self, from: "\(selectedCategory).json") 
    navigationController?.pushViewController(selectedVC, animated: true)
  }
}
```

...

```
class SelectImageViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedArray = [Images]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       ...
    }
```

Or if you really want to decode the array in  `SelectImageViewController`

```
extension MenuViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

...

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectImageViewController") as! SelectImageViewController
    selectedVC.selectedCategory = categories[indexPath.row].category
    navigationController?.pushViewController(selectedVC, animated: true)
  }
}
```

...

```
class SelectImageViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedCategory = ""

    var selectedArray = [Images]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        selectedArray = Bundle.main.decode([Images].self, from: "\(selectedCategory).json") 
        ...
    }
```